# An error occurred during client rendering

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report which works without problems. I created a new version of that report with two levels of grouping, which works perfectly in Visual Studio. I deployed it to the server (in SharePoint integration mode). The report runs for a while (displaying the spinner) and then I get the error:

> An error occurred during client rendering

So it appears to collate the data but chokes when trying to render it.

I can render the report from the server directly to PDF and Excel and that renders correctly. It is just when it tries to render in the browser that it doesn't render.

The Reporting Services log simply shows that it processed the report and doesn't have any errors.

Has anyone got any clues to what might cause this?

Comment: What happens if you render to *HTML* on the server?

Comment: I don't have a HTML option, but MHTML also chokes. Word and CSV render correctly. Everything other than HTML rendering works.

Comment: I wasn't aware of any such bugs with the HTML renderer. I think all you may have left is some [binary search debugging](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/50552/how-to-effectively-do-manual-debugging/181223#181223) to find the offending element in your report. When you do, be sure to let us know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When rendering to HTML in Visual Studio (using the save button after rendering in VS) it gave me the following error message:

> An error occurred during local report processing.
>
> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>
> Parameter name: index

I found [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2b921e79-a618-4cd7-8d71-84ef9c40ec6d/index-was-out-of-range-must-be-nonnegative-and-less-than-the-size-of-the-collection-parameter) which suggested that it was to do with items in the header or footer being to big for the header or footer, and particularly mentions images. I have an image in the header. My image looked fine but was 0.00475cm in from the left margin when it should be flush left (and was flush left in the report that this report was copied from). I changed it to be positioned at 0,0 and the report now renders in HTML.

Its the little things...

Answer (score 0):

When I get the error:

```
An error occurred during client rendering.
An error has occurred during report processing.
The data source 'XYZDataSource' cannot be found.
```

It always happens after I Deploy reports to the server from BIDS.

To resolve it, I *close the Browser (page) and* **start a new Browser window**, put in the URL and it works again.

Answer (score 0):

I received this same error when I had a line at the bottom of a header which was somehow covered by the body.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error when I had tables inside tables, and the inner tables had column visibility expressions. When every column's visibility expression resulted in a false value (causing them all to be hidden), then I would get this error. I added an extra super thin column in the row, and then it was fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).