# MS ReportViewer WinForms Excel Export Error

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

I have a report rdlc file in my C# VS2012 application. The report displays normally in the application and also works fine to export it to MS Word or PDF. But the Excel export fails with the error: 'An error occurred during local report processing. Length cannot be less than zero. Parameter name:length'

I don't have any custom parameters named length.

This is the code that generates the report. I added some custom parameters to add footer information. Any idea what may be causing the problem? Or how to go about troubleshooting it?

```
private void frmReportViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataTable1BindingSource.DataSource = ReportData();

        RunStat thisRun = SurveyTools.RunStatistics(runID);
        string avgSpeed = thisRun.AverageSpeed.ToString("N2");

        List<ReportParameter> myParams = new List<ReportParameter>();

        myParams.Add(new ReportParameter("PLDistance", thisRun.RunDistance.ToString("N0")));
        myParams.Add(new ReportParameter("RunHours", thisRun.RunHours.ToString("N2")));
        myParams.Add(new ReportParameter("AvgSpeed", avgSpeed));
        rptView.LocalReport.SetParameters(myParams);
        rptView.SetDisplayMode(DisplayMode.PrintLayout);

        this.rptView.RefreshReport();
    }

    private DataTable ReportData()...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15216711/an-error-occurred-during-client-rendering) which gave the same error except it was a parameter called index that failed on HTML rendering but worked for every other renderer.

What happened in that instance was that I upgraded an SSRS 2005 report to SSRS 2008 and something got misaligned in the conversion. SSRS now thinks that you have a text box or something with a negative length. When it talks about a parameter called length, it doesn't mean one of your report parameters but a parameter that is part of the XML that is used internally to size your report objects. Your report probably looks fine but something has gone wrong in the code.

It is a process of re-positioning and re-sizing report objects until you find the one that is causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating two reports. One for export to PDF with all of the nice header and footer test. The other explicitly for export to Excel. I removed all of the footer textboxes from the Excel version. It is working fine.